# $P( A\triangle B ) = 0 \Rightarrow P(A)=P(B)=P(A\cup B) + P(A \cap B) $

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, self-learning

> > I want to prove the following statement;
> >
> > $$P( A\triangle B ) = 0 \Rightarrow P(A)=P(B)=P(A\cup B) \color{blue}{=} P(A \cap B) $$

---

What I did is that

$$P(A\triangle B) =P((A\setminus B ) \cup (B\setminus A))=0$$

$$=P((A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap A^c))=0$$

$$=P((A\cup B)\cap (A\cup A^c)\cap (B\cup B^c)\cap(B^c \cup B^c))=0$$

$$=P((A\cup B)\cap (B^c\cup A^c))=0$$

$$=P((A\cup B)\setminus (B\cap A))=0$$

Please help me showing this. thank you.

Comment: I think $P$ is a probability function for the OP.

Comment: yes P is probability function @MichaelBurr

Comment: The plus in the conclusion should be an equality,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probabilities have to look like this, from which everything follows.

[image]